# Kernels and Epimorphisms ("Epic Morphisms") as quotients of vector spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $f: A \to B$ be a monomorphism of vector spaces. We know that $\text{coker}(f)= B/A$. Is there a similar relationship between $\ker(g)$ and quotients with $M$ and $N$ given an epimorphism $g: M \to N$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear to me what you would consider a "similar" relationship or why you would expect there to be one.  From a categorical perspective, I would say that the analogue of $\operatorname{coker}(f)=B/A$ is that the kernel of $g$ (defined categorically) is the kernel of $g$ (defined as the subspace of those $v\in M$ such that $g(v)=0$).

But if you want some statement in terms of quotients, you can say that $N$ is isomorphic to the quotient $M/\ker(g)$.  This holds more generally in an abelian category: an epimorphism is the cokernel of its kernel.  Because we're dealing with vector spaces so every epimorphism splits, you could also choose a splitting $i:N\to M$ of $g$ and get a (highly noncanonical) isomorphism $\ker(g)\cong M/N$ (where the "$N$" in the quotient is really the image of $i$).

Answer (score 2):

A consequence of the first isomorphism theorem is that in that case $M/\ker(g) \cong N$.

By choosing a section $N \to M$ that splits $g$, one could even treat $N$ as a subspace of $M$ and say that $\ker(g) \cong M/N$. I don't see any advantage of considering this viewpoint, however.